# PHP type juggling and decrement operator

Tags: php, type-conversion, decrement

I am playing with the `for-loop` and `CLI` in PHP. I am having issue with decrement operator(--). Below is my code,

```
<?php

    $handle = fopen("php://stdin","r");
    $str = fgets($handle);
    for($i=$str; $i>0; $i--){   
        var_dump($i);
    }
```

It goes in to infinite loop for any number > 0. below is the output,

```
john@doe:/var/www/html/rank$ php 1.php
3
string(2) "3
"
string(2) "3
"
string(2) "3
"
string(2) "3
"
string(2) "3
"
string(2) "3
"
```

but if I explicitly type cast cli argument to `int`, it works,

```
<?php

    $handle = fopen("php://stdin","r");
    $str = (int)fgets($handle);
    for($i=$str; $i>0; $i--){   
        var_dump($i);
    }
```

Output

```
john@doe:/var/www/html/rank$ php 1.php
3
int(3)
int(2)
int(1)
john@doe:/var/www/html/rank$
```

Am I doing something wrong or type juggling does not work with decrement operator(intentionally)? as it seems working okay with increment operator(++) as below

```
<?php

    $handle = fopen("php://stdin","r");
    $str = fgets($handle);
    for($i="1"; $i<=$str; $i++){    
        var_dump($i);
    }
```

Output

```
john@doe:/var/www/html/rank$ php 1.php
3
string(1) "1"
int(2)
int(3)
john@doe:/var/www/html/rank$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a line break in the `$str` you are getting from the file:

```
string(2) "3
"
```

So the ascii characters of the string are `#51` (dec. ASCII code for char "3") and `#10` (dec. ASCII code for line feed).
If you are using the decrement operator `i--` the string will change to `#51#09`. The next iteration will change it to `#51#08`.

The first character will not be changed, because the second character will be decremented. That's the reason why it looks like there is not decrementation.

**Solution:**

If you change

```
$str = fgets($handle);
```

to

```
$str = trim(fgets($handle));
```

the line feeds, tabs etc. will be removed to that the decrement operator will decrement the character `#51`.